# Django not sending JSON response through nginx, instead sends HTML

Tags: python, json, django, nginx, gunicorn

I set up an API with Django through nginx and I'm trying to hit an endpoint with a Node app but the response that I receive is basically the index.html file instead of JSON.

Here's my .conf in sites-available (fake_watson is the api and chat is the node app):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 10.39.40.107;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/fake_watson_frontend/build;
    }

    location /fake_watson/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/fake_watson_backend/fake_watson_backend.sock;
        charset_types application/json;
        default_type application/json;
        add_header content_type application/json;
        proxy_set_header content_type application/json;
    }

    location /chat/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

My code in Django looks like this (probabilities is a dict):

```
import json 
from .models import Input, Classification 
from .classifier import Classifier 
from django.http import JsonResponse 

# Create your views here. 
def predict(request, input): 
    probabilities = Classifier.predict(input) 
    return JsonResponse(probabilities)
```

Through my axios call, response.data looks like this: `"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"><title>React App</title><link href="/static/css/main.9a0fe4f1.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.bff3100f.js"></script></body></html>"`

Lastly, application/json is included in my mimetypes.  If it helps, my content-type headers are still "text/html; charset=UTF-8".

I've been looking all over for a straightforward answer but I haven't seemed to find anything - any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Through my axios call, response.data looks like this:" you forgot to copy pate whatever it is that you intended to copy paste.

Comment: Does the request get passed through to django? check the wsgi log file